# Can't get response from https://kubernetes.default

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cluster that was recently upgraded. Since then none of the pods running in the cluster are able to get a response from https://kubernetes.default/healthz.

To be clear, they can **resolve** the URL, but it constantly times out of comes back with connection refused.

I have verified that the api-server is running as I can get a response from http://localhost:8080/healthz, but I can't get anything from within a pod.

I've checked all the scripts and configs and compared them to the other clusters that were upgraded at the same time and there appears to be nothing different.

I'm sure it's something small I've overlooked but I don't know where else to look.

Additional information:

- setup was with kops
- runs in AWS (not the managed services but raw)
- the above queries work as expected in other clusters
- upgrade was from 1.11 to 1.13 (yes, I know that is frowned upon. At least now I do.)
- other clusters had same upgrade path

[edit]

providing /etc/resolv.conf

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 100.64.0.10
search jenkins.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local us-west-2.compute.internal
options ndots:5
```

Comment: provide pod's `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @VKR resolv.conf added

Answer (score 6):

Check the image I uploaded, you can only resolve the **dns** `kubernetes` from within a pod in the `default` namespace. For other namespaces use `kubernetes.default.svc` like in the following curl. You have the certificate and token already mounted in the pod as well.

`curl --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" -H "Accept: application/json"  https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/`

[image]

Comment: So this is what I get:
    /# curl --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" -H "Accept: application/json"  https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/  
    curl: (7) Failed to connect to kubernetes.default.svc port 443: Connection timed out   
    /#

and if I run `kubectl -n jenkins exec -ti busybox nslookup kubernetes.default` it resolves:
  
Server:  100.64.0.1   
Address: 100.64.0.10#53 

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local  
Address: 100.64.0.1

Comment: Great, then for your kubernetes version you have to use `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` instead of the one I provided you. My cluster is 1.11.x

Comment: Even using `curl --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" -H "Accept: application/json"  https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local/api/` still returns with `curl: (7) Failed to connect to kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local port 443: Connection timed out`